# Add subview to specific view

Tags: ios

I have a static table, one cell has multiple views that I would like to add subviews.  Each view has a class (MHRotaryKnob) assigned.

What I can't figure out is how to ID each view in the cell so I can addSubView.

I have set up the table within StoryBoard.

Comment: provide a tag for each view. you can do that in storyboard. then you can get the needed view by tag.

Comment: Is that a simple table like in an `NSArray` or do you mean a `TableView`?

Comment: Andrey- how to access the tag and apply the addSubView?

Comment: SOLVED - Thanks!!!   [[[self view] viewWithTag:1] addSubview:rotaryKnob];

Answer (score 0):

Give your Viewcontroller an IBOutlet-Property for a UIView like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *myView;
```

then connect those to your desired view in storyboards.
now you can address this view in code like this:

```
[self.myView addSubview:subView];
```

Thats probably easier than messing with ids or tags.

If you have problems, this will help you:
http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-A-Beginners-Guide-to-Storyboard-Connection

EDIT:

If you want ta add a subview to a MHRotaryKnob, you can just go the other way around:

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MHRotaryKnob *myKnob;
```

and then, assuming that MHRotaryKnob is a direct or indirect subclass of UIView, you can add the subview:

```
[self.myKnob addSubview:subView];
```

Comment: The view has a specific class associated with it.  When I create the IBOutlet is uses the class name - IBOutlet MHRotaryKnob *myView;  Which then makes *myView not a UIView.

Comment: @Ned - maybe i misunderstood. are you trying to add a MHRotaryKnob-Object to a UIView or the other way around?

Comment: k-  Looking to add a MHRotaryKNob-ojbect to a UIView.  Solved with: [[[self view] viewWithTag:1] addSubview:rotaryKnob];

Comment: @Ned - Glad to hear you solved it, but that would have worked with my first solution. I would suggest you read that link i posted, since its a pretty basic technique and tags will become bothersome if the structure is more complex.